# How to add files to ipfs with pure javascript only?

Tags: javascript, ipfs, nft, decentralized-applications

I have tried to find some examples but all of them have lost relevance.. I have tried also to use infure but it is not for free now.. Maybe someone knows the solution, I need it for automatic loading of NFT images.

js-ipfs
ipfs-core
ipfs-http-client

Answer (score 0):

Hi I recommend familiarising with the IPFS concepts as [IPFS is not a storage provider to add files to](https://docs.ipfs.tech/concepts/what-is-ipfs/#what-ipfs-isn-t).

For storing NFT images on IPFS, the official [IPFS docs recommend services](https://docs.ipfs.tech/how-to/mint-nfts-with-ipfs/#a-short-introduction-to-nfts) like [Pinata](https://pinata.cloud/) and [nft.storage](https://nft.storage/). There should be some free tiers which are available for experimentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried Pinata and understand how to upload images or json. Also I need to upload two json files so they are in the same folder and I need access to them in the form ipfs://QmSi82a57Kx7sMB4AGeW1sFZNvNQbqvE8s3udUdXTbQDdN/1 Is it possible to do with Pinata? Could you give example?